# How to parse an embed tag of a video?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to parse an embed tag from a video by Simple HTML DOM parser. I've spent 7 days to parse embed tag of this video, but until now I still can not parse embed tag from this video. I really don't understand why Simple HTML DOM parser can not parse this embed tag, the others tag it can parse easily.

file.php

```
include_once ("simple_html_dom.php");
$source = 'http://www.cliphai.com/2014/05/surprise-rollercoaster.html';
$html = file_get_html($source);

echo $html->find('embed',0);
```

Comment: The content seems to be loaded using javascript, unfortunately Simple HTML DOM cannot handle it...

Answer (score 2):

Your website has this code:

```
<embed name="flashplayer" src="http://player.k24h.com/player.swf" flashvars="plugins=http://player.k24h.com/plugins/proxy.swf&amp;proxy.link=http://www.youtube.com/v/gHmMszbgimY&amp;autostart=true&amp;controlbar.position=over" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" autostart="true" width="100%" height="100%" quality="low">
```

But it only appears when website is rendered, you won't find it in HTML.

Looks like just routes to youtube video http://www.youtube.com/v/gHmMszbgimY

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an `<embed>` tag in the source code of that page, so that's probably the reason why your DOM parser can't find it...